What are the different conditions for the Newtonian limit of General Relativity and for Special Relativity?
Both the Newtonian limit and Special Relativity seem to be limits of General Relativity, but they are not the same limit. They occur when there is weaker gravity, but do they differ when the relative velocity is 0 and when the relative velocity is the speed of light in vacuo? What conditions make them different limits of General Relativity?

What, precisely, do you mean by "the Newtonian limit"? Are you referring to Newtonian gravity, or Newtonian mechanics?

If that's the case, the limits would just be $v\ll c$ for Newtonian mechanics and $h_{\mu\nu}\ll 1$ for Newtonian gravity (where $h$ is the perturbation to the metric tensor). Special relativity is sort of the limiting case of general relativity where $h_{\mu\nu}=0$.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+t+with+respect+to+r+where+t+%3D+sqrt%281+-+R%2Fr%29

What I mean by "the Newtonian limit" is Newtonian gravity.

In addition to @JEB's answer, it may be useful be consider the so-called
"Bronstein cube" (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGh_physics ),
where General Relativity is a corner of a cube, and
Classical Gravitation and Special Relativity are corners adjacent to General Relativity.
Newtonian Classical Mechanics is at the origin of the cube,
and the three axes correspond to fundamental constants
$1/c$, $G$, and $h$---as if one can "dial down" the value of fundamental constant. (Of course, some details are needed to properly formulate such limits in a particular model.)
Here is the classical (non-quantum) face of the cube:

$(0,0,0)$ is Newtonian Classical Mechanics
$(1,0,0)$ is Special Relativity
$(0,1,0)$ is Newtonian Gravitation
$(1,1,0)$ is General Relativity

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGh_physics


The cube has its origins with Matvei Bronstein's PhD dissertation,
regarded as the first dissertation on quantum gravity.

From the answer by @ccampisano for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14181/source-documents-for-bronsteins-cube-of-physics




The two limits are low speed:
$$ v \ll c $$
where violations can be handled in the Post-Minkowskian expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Minkowskian_expansion).
and non-compact:
$$ R/M \ll R_S/M = \frac{2G}{c^2} $$
which leads to post-newtonian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion) formalism.
In these limits, four velocity:
$$ u_{\mu} \approx (c, \vec v) $$
and the stress energy tensor is dominated by:
$$ T_{tt} \propto mc^2 $$
(rest energy, which is mass).
Meanwhile the Schwarzschild metric radial dependences are
$$ g^2_{tt} = 1-\frac{R_s}r $$
$$ g^2_{rr} = (1-\frac{R_s}r)^{-1} $$
and the geodesic equation is dominated by the
$tt$ term (since it mixes with $c$, while $rr$ mixes with $v\ll c$ in the geodesic eq.).
Note that:
$$ 1 - \frac{R_S} r = 1-\frac{2GM/r}{c^2} = 
1-\Phi(r)/c^2 $$
where $\Phi(r)$ is the standard Newtonian potential (per unit mass)...and it's size relative to $c^2$ (rest energy per unit mass) determines the deviation from flat-time.

You got you PN and PM mixed up
